# Loot tables in d3?

Tags: diablo-iii

I was wondering if the loot in diablo 3 is random throughout the game or is it viable to "farm" specific bosses for specific gear? Are there loot tables for bosses and if so, where can I find them?

Comment: Pretty sure it's all random

Comment: Higher difficulties result in lesser chance of finding items. Bosses drop more items first kill, so champions/elites are best for farming.

Comment: So Leorics crown might drop from a broken barrel but not the Skeleton King himself? Sounds odd...

Comment: @Domocus: Do you have a citation for the bit about bosses dropping less items on subsequent kills?

Comment: Only the first kill will yield higher amount of items. If you searched the site, you would see at least two questions concerning this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the items that you get are entirely random (the item type is random, the number of affixes on an item is random to an extent, and the values of the affixes themselves are random within a given range for the item's level).

The only things that are set, as far as I know, are that higher-difficulty monsters (e.g. Champions/Rares/Bosses) have a greater chance to drop higher-quality items as well as in greater numbers, and that certain tiers of items can only appear on Nightmare, Hell, or Inferno difficulties.

There are reports of people receiving legendary drops from plain old white-named enemies, so anything is possible. (A little Magic Find doesn't hurt, either. :))

Comment: While it is random it is not entirely random, most items and affixes have level reqs, but if you want to farm high end items this will not matter, but if you are looking for a lower level item you can farm lower level mobs to exclude higher level items having a chance of dropping.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, Jay Wilson has stated loot tables work exactly the same as in D2. It may seem random/arbitrary, but it is (supposedly) by design:

> The mechanic is exactly the same as Diablo 2, and as you describe it hear. And the loot tables are not more vast than D2 because we don't allow items to drop below level 50 in Inferno.

source: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/6317360#magicfind

Comment: Magic Find works exactly the same as Diablo 2; loot tables are something entirely different.

Answer (score -2):

Would love to point that Jonathan is correct. I farm for hours a day when I'm off of work. Here's how I see the table working...

1-70 magic find I usually have a higher chance for a rare, but always find blues quicker.

You have to realize, magic find affects every items table. If one item has a 0.25% chance to drop. +100% magic find would in theory make it now 0.5%

I've also realized when I have around 150 - 240 magic, I get at least two rares per elite pack, sometimes three or four rares from a single group. Without magic find, I usualy get one, rarely two, and sometimes none from an elite group.

Yesterday I had a legendary unique drop off of a trash mob in Act 1 Inferno, then later that day a legendary axe off of another trash mob. So yes, although the table is prolly far less. Trash mobs have a chance to drop the same stuff. So put up that magic find and happy hunting :)

Comment: Your math is off.  0.2% + 100% != 0.3%.  And what does this have to do with loot tables?

Comment: So I think it's dependant on the Act, like if I remember correctly in Hell and in Nightmare it was the same. Act 1 and 2 had lower then act 3 and 4. So I would think if you want higher items. Act 3 would be a great place to start.

Comment: lol there is no set loot table in diablo thanks for giving me the -1 though makes me look like I know nothing :P

Comment: Then your answer should reflect your latest comment; this answer doesn't answer the question.

Comment: In comparison it does, it gives the person asking the question a better way to find what he's looking for. Even if it does not answer his question per say. Giving him an alternate solution is a prize in itself. Going around and just bluntly saying everyone is wrong makes you look like a fool. Instead of that, give your own advice. Perhaps it's better then mine.